# GNU grub 2.0 minimal bash-like line editing is supported message appears

Tags: 18.04, grub2, uefi, gpt

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad l340. I installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode.

I liked installing Ubuntu 18.04 but this problem appears to me `GNU grub version 2.02 minimal bash-like line editing is supported......`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Disable **Secure Boot** in your BIOS configuration.

> You may need to disable Secure Boot to run some PC graphics cards,
>   hardware, or operating systems such as Linux or previous version of
>   Windows.

[Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/disabling-secure-boot). 
[Additional info](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/925971) in case of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 UEFI.